# Can't assign text to a const in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to assign text from a txt file to a variable in node but it gives an 'undefined' error. What am I doing wrong?

```
const fs = require('fs');

const floor = 0;

const text = fs.readFile('./aaa.txt', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('errrrrroorrrrr!');
    }
    text = data.toString();
})

console.log(text);
```

Comment: You have already declared `const text`, so you cannot reassign it. I would use fs.readFileSync, and then use the value.

Comment: You probably don't know you are working with callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you're working with callbacks, so when you do `console.log`, the reading operation might not be finished yet.

Another problem is that you're trying to reassign `text` constant. You can't reassign constants.

I would suggest using `fs.readFileSync` which will read your file synchronously (Do not do this if you have a *big file*).

```
const text = fs.readFileSync('./aaa.txt', 'utf8');
```

If you have a big file, you would have to work continue your logic inside your callback like this:

```
fs.readFile('./aaa.txt', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('errrrrroorrrrr!');
    }
    const text = data.toString();
    console.log(text);
})
```

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to assign the same const `text` twice. What you can do is:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./aaa.txt', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('errrrrroorrrrr!');
    }
    const text = data.toString();
    console.log(text);
})
```

Or, as @bhuvnesh pattnaik mentioned, you can do it like this:

```js
let text = ``;
const textRead = fs.readFile('./aaa.txt', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('errrrrroorrrrr!');
    }
    text = data.toString();
});
console.log(text); //console output is ''
```

but be careful with this option, because the callback in `readFile` doesn't happen right away, and the value might still not be there when you need it.

Comment: But I won't be able to access text outside of the function. If i do a console.log outside of the readfile function, it gives error.

Comment: Yep, that is right. Could you elaborate on how do you want to use it outside?

Comment: If i do a console.log(text) outside of the function, it should be able to output the text.

Comment: The value won't be there right after you call `readFile`, because the assignment happens in the callback.

Comment: Take a look at @Dan Cantir 's suggestion with `readFileSync`. It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, the readFIleSync option is better coz I dont get any value with your alternative option.

Answer (score 2):

in your code,

text is const type, so you cannot re-assign a value to it,

Either make text as let or var

OR

use another variable inside to assign the data.toString()

You should do something like below:

```
let text = ``;
const textRead = fs.readFile('./aaa.txt', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('errrrrroorrrrr!');
    }
    text = data.toString();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have to use it in async function only.

```
import fs from 'fs';
const text = await fs.promises.readFile('./aaa.txt');
```